# Eclipse - Android SDK: enabling Android items in menu?

Tags: eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I'm using Eclipse 3.5 with the Android SDK. Last time I installed the SDK, the Android items (like, create new Android project and create new XML) all showed up in the menus without having to click other. Any idea how to make those show up in the menus? Also, how do I enable the +/- for adding layouts/widgets in the resource editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for Android perspective. You can switch perspective in the upper right corner. The Android perspective is going to put all Android-specific items within easier reach.

Comment: which perspective do i choose? i see ddms, debug, etc. Is it plug-in dev?

Comment: i would have expected something obviously labeled "android". you could try ddms, that's android-related. plugin-dev is for developing eclipse plugins. debug is general debugging. java is general java development. resource is the the most basic perspective without language specific stuff.

Comment: try java perspective too. it is possible that android sdk is adding its ui items there.

Comment: uh, i dont want the ddms. also, im using the java perspective right now.

Comment: Well, I am stumped... either (a) the android sdk has changed recently to remove or move these items or (b) somehow you didn't install all of the android sdk

Comment: Thought of another possibility... Some plugins require Eclipse to run on a specific version of Java. If Eclipse starts on an older JVM, those plugins silently don't activate. On windows, it is common for Eclipse to pickup Microsoft's ancient JVM. On many linux distros, it is equally common to pickup Open JDK 1.4, which is too old for many plugins. Check the JVM location / version in Help -> About -> Installation Details -> Configuration. If you find that the wrong JVM is used, edit your eclipse.ini file and add -vm switch followed by path JVM location on a separate line.

Comment: Try Oracle/Sun JDK. I have heard nothing but complaints from people trying to run Eclipse on OpenJDK.